# In formidable form.parse throw keyword not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

with throw keyword its not working everytime i hit th route always gives me error pointing toword throw keyword  and if i remove throw its works check code for reference i have my custom error handler in server.js which is working fine with others exports

```
exports.createMainCategory = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.keepExtensions = true;
    
      form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400);
          throw new Error("problem with image");
        }
        const { maincategory } = fields;
    
        if (!maincategory) {
          //NOT WORKING WITH THIS
    
          res.status(400);
          throw new Error("include all files");
    
          // ONLY WORKIN WITH BELOW CODE
    
          // return res.status(400).json({
          //   error: "Please include all fields",
          // });
        }
    
        let mainCat = new MainCat(fields);
    
        //handle file here
        if (file.photo) {
          if (file.photo.size > 3000000) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error("File size too big!");
          }
          mainCat.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.path);
          mainCat.photo.contentType = file.photo.type;
        }
    
        //save to the DB
    
        mainCat.save((err, mcategory) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
              error: "Saving category in DB failed",
            });
          }
          res.json(mcategory);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: if you are using express you are not supposed to throw but next(error) instead

Comment: thanks mate, you resolve my doubt :D